# AS3 object array to class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object, instance, movieclip

I am new and having an issue with the use of classes in as3.
I have created an array of objects in my main timeline

```
    function badPlayer() 
    {
        var bads:Array = new Array();
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) 
        {
            var mc = new bman();
            mc.name=["mc"+i];
            bads.push(mc); 
            _backGround.addChild(mc);
            mc.x = 100;
            mc.y = 100;
            trace (bads);
            Baddies(_backGround.mc); //here I am trying to export mc to my class
        }
    }
```

Here is a snip-it from my class. My trace statement wont even output.

```
    public class Baddies extends MovieClip
{
    private var pistolSound:pistolShot = new pistolShot();
    //private var mc = new mc();
    private var _rotateSpeedMax:Number = 2;
    private var _gravity:Number = .68;
    private var _bulletSpeed:Number = 2;        
    private var _maxDistance:Number = 200;
    private var _reloadSpeed:Number = 500; //milliseconds
    private var _barrelLength:Number = 20;
    private var _bulletSpread:Number = 5;
    private var _isLoaded:Boolean = true;       
    private var _isFiring:Boolean = true;
    private var _endX:Number;
    private var _endY:Number;
    private var _startX:Number;
    private var _startY:Number;
    private var _reloadTimer:Timer;
    private var _bullets:Array = [];
    private var _gun:MovieClip;
    private var _enemy:MovieClip;
    private var _yx:Number;
    private var _yy:Number;
    private var _pcos:Number;
    private var _psin:Number;
    private var _trueRotation:Number;
    public function Baddies() 
    {
        trace("working");
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }
```

Basically I am trying to create several bad guys (bman) and have the same code apply to each of them. I have also tried to change the linkage name of bman to Baddies with no success.

Comment: Your probably not calling the `badPlayer()` function, but even if you did, there's a whole mess of other problems with your code. If I understood want your aim with `Baddies(_backGround.mc);` was, I(or someone else) could rewrite the entire thing for you.  By the way `Baddies(_background,mc)` converts `_background.mc` to a `Baddies` object.

Comment: lol... I am calling the badPlayer() function. I am trying to create a function that will dynamically create a number of badguys. This is a platform style game where I want each of the badguys point and shoot at the player. _backGround is the instance of my platform world and each mc or "bman" is the badguys. This is the 1st game I have done where I am actually using external AS files and I am so confused. If I had just coded this whole game on the main timeline I would probably be wrapping up the game by now.

Comment: I was able to get my code to work properly when I physically put one instance of bman on the stage. But I want to have several badguys and place them each in a random location on the platform world. When I attempted to addChild all hell broke loose lol

Comment: "If I understood want your aim with Baddies(_backGround.mc); was, I(or someone else) could rewrite the entire thing for you."        
Baddies is an external AS file that makes the movie clip point at the player and shoot.

Comment: This code  Baddies(_backGround.mc); will break your compile. You should be getting an error on the lines of expected parameters 0. If you are not getting any errors then there is another issue with your IDE. What IDE are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few thing that are very wrong with this code.

```
Baddies(_backGround.mc); //here I am trying to export mc to my class
```

This is a typecast, as already stated in the comments. By the way *Baddies* isn't a good name, because it plural. You probably want to create a *new* bad guy, which would be done with this line:

```
var baddie = new Baddies();
```

Now your constructor uses the `stage` variable. This won't work because the object isn't on the stage, therefore `stage` is `null` (it may works if you drag and drop an instance to the stage in the editor). So before using the `stage` you actually need to add the object to the stage:

```
public function Baddies() {
    trace("new baddie created");
}

public function init(mc:MovieClip) {
    mc.addChild(this); // display this baddie
    trace("working");
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
}
```

And in the `badPlayer` function:

```
var baddie = new Baddies();
baddie.init(_backGround);
```

Comment: Thanks a million kapep... I have a whole slew of new errors but they are not related and I should have no problem working through them :D

Comment: Everything is up and running... Thanks again